# Simple pack Uri builder

Tags: c#, design-patterns, wpf

I want to make the creation of the pack Uri for WPF resources more verbose so they are *easier* to read and less error-prone and I thought I implement it using the builder pattern.

---

The base class for each builder (there are four of them) is the `PackUriBuilder`. It implements the `UriKind` logic, checks the path and requries the derived class to implement the `AbsolutePath` property. It also provides static methods to initialize each of the builders.

*(I omitted null checks to make is shorter).*

```
abstract class PackUriBuilder
{
    private string _path;
    private UriKind _uriKind;

    protected PackUriBuilder(string path)
    {
        if (!path.StartsWith("/")) throw new ArgumentException(paramName: nameof(path), message: "Path must start with \"/\".");
        _path = path;
        _uriKind = UriKind.Absolute;
    }

    public string Scheme => "pack";

    public string RelativePath => _path;

    public abstract string AbsolutePath { get; }

    public static implicit operator string (PackUriBuilder builder) => builder.ToString();

    public static implicit operator Uri(PackUriBuilder builder)
    {
        switch (builder._uriKind)
        {
            case UriKind.Absolute:
                return new Uri(builder.ToString(), UriKind.Absolute);
            case UriKind.Relative:
                return new Uri(builder.RelativePath, UriKind.Relative);
        }
        // todo: I know this needs a better message ;-)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Invalid UriKind.");
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        switch (_uriKind)
        {
            case UriKind.Absolute:
                return AbsolutePath;
            case UriKind.Relative:
                return RelativePath;
        }
        // todo: I know this needs a better message ;-)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Invalid UriKind.");
    }

    public Uri ToUri() => (Uri)this;

    public PackUriBuilder Relative()
    {
        _uriKind = UriKind.Relative;
        return this;
    }

    public PackUriBuilder Absolute()
    {
        _uriKind = UriKind.Absolute;
        return this;
    }

    public static LocalAssemblyResourceFilePackUriBuilder LocalAssemblyResourceFile(string path)
    {
        return new LocalAssemblyResourceFilePackUriBuilder(path);
    }

    public static ReferencedAssemblyResourceFilePackUriBuilder ReferencedAssemblyResourceFile(string path, string assemblyShortName)
    {
        return new ReferencedAssemblyResourceFilePackUriBuilder(path, assemblyShortName);
    }

    public static ContentFilePackUriBuilder ContentFile(string path)
    {
        return new ContentFilePackUriBuilder(path);
    }

    public static SiteOfOriginPackUriBuilder SiteOfOrigin(string path)
    {
        return new SiteOfOriginPackUriBuilder(path);
    }
}
```

These are the four builders for each pack Uri type.

```
class LocalAssemblyResourceFilePackUriBuilder : PackUriBuilder
{
    public LocalAssemblyResourceFilePackUriBuilder(string path) 
    : base(path) { }

    public override string AbsolutePath
    {
        get
        {
            return $"{Scheme}://application:,,,{RelativePath}";
        }
    }
}

class ReferencedAssemblyResourceFilePackUriBuilder : PackUriBuilder
{
    private string _assemblyShortName;
    private string _version;
    private string _publicKey;

    public ReferencedAssemblyResourceFilePackUriBuilder(string path, string assemblyShortName) 
    : base(path)
    {
        _assemblyShortName = assemblyShortName;
    }

    public ReferencedAssemblyResourceFilePackUriBuilder Version(string version)
    {
        _version = version;
        return this;
    }

    public ReferencedAssemblyResourceFilePackUriBuilder PublicKey(string publicKey)
    {
        _publicKey = publicKey;
        return this;
    }

    public override string AbsolutePath
    {
        get
        {
            var version = string.IsNullOrEmpty(_version) ? string.Empty : $";{_version}";
            var publicKey = string.IsNullOrEmpty(_publicKey) ? string.Empty : $";{_publicKey}";
            return $"{Scheme}://application:,,,/{_assemblyShortName}{version}{publicKey};component{RelativePath}";
        }
    }
}

class ContentFilePackUriBuilder : PackUriBuilder
{
    public ContentFilePackUriBuilder(string path) 
    : base(path) { }

    public override string AbsolutePath
    {
        get
        {
            return $"{Scheme}://application:,,,{RelativePath}";
        }
    }
}

class SiteOfOriginPackUriBuilder : PackUriBuilder
{
    public SiteOfOriginPackUriBuilder(string path) 
    : base(path) { }

    public override string AbsolutePath
    {
        get
        {
            return $"{Scheme}://siteoforigin:,,,{RelativePath}";
        }
    }
}
```

---

## Examples

```
// LINQPad requires this because it's not running in WPF context.
if (!UriParser.IsKnownScheme("pack")) { new System.Windows.Application(); }

PackUriBuilder.LocalAssemblyResourceFile("/test.bmp").ToString().Dump();
PackUriBuilder.ReferencedAssemblyResourceFile("/test.bmp", "MyAssembly").Version("v2.3.0.1").ToString().Dump();
PackUriBuilder.SiteOfOrigin("/test.bmp").Relative().ToString().Dump();
```

Output:

```
pack://application:,,,/test.bmp
pack://application:,,,/MyAssembly;v2.3.0.1;component/test.bmp
/test.bmp
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code looks pretty got but there are some things that you can simplify, probably the switch cases are the most unwanted part of your code.

### Verbatim strings

`"Path must start with \"/\"."`

Can become

`@"Path must start with ""/""."`

### `get` only properties

```
private string _path;
public string RelativePath => _path;
```

Can become

```
public string RelativePath { get; }
```

### `get` only properties, without a backing field

You can use expression bodies for all of your `get` only properties, without a backing field:

```
public override string AbsolutePath
{
    get
    {
        return $"{Scheme}://application:,,,{RelativePath}";
    }
}
```

Can become

```
public override string AbsolutePath => $"{Scheme}://siteoforigin:,,,{RelativePath}";
```

You can do the same for all of the `AbsolutePath` properties.

`private string _assemblyShortName;` can be a `readonly` variable

### Redundant casts

```
public Uri ToUri() => (Uri) this;
```

You already have an implicit operator that does that for you

```
public static implicit operator Uri(PackUriBuilder builder)
```

### Replacing the nasty `switch case` with a `Dictionary`

```
public static implicit operator Uri(PackUriBuilder builder)
{
    switch (builder._uriKind)
    {
        case UriKind.Absolute:
            return new Uri(builder.ToString(), UriKind.Absolute);
        case UriKind.Relative:
             return new Uri(builder.RelativePath, UriKind.Relative);
    }
        // todo: I know this needs a better message ;-)
   throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Invalid UriKind.");
}
```

With a dictionary looking similar to this one

```
protected static Dictionary<UriKind, Func<PackUriBuilder, Uri>> helper = new Dictionary
        <UriKind, Func<PackUriBuilder, Uri>>
        {
            {UriKind.Absolute, builder => new Uri(builder.ToString(), UriKind.Absolute)},
            {UriKind.Relative, builder => new Uri(builder.RelativePath, UriKind.Relative)}
        };
```

Can become

```
public static implicit operator Uri(PackUriBuilder builder) => helper[builder._uriKind].Invoke(builder);
```

Your `public override string ToString()` is similar but it might be a little bit more harder to do with a dictionary, since there are some virtual variables involved, namely `AbsolutePath` and since you can't make it into a static variable and initialize it like the helper dictionary used for the implicit operator, You might need to initialize the dictionary from the constructor but as you know virtual calls can be very tricky if called in the constructor.

Comment: I guess there is not much more to improve. I'm embarassed as usually I write similar reviews but when you look at your own code you have sometimes a blind spot.

Comment: I completely agree happens to me all the time too..

Answer (score 5):

You're likely to run across 101 different little gotchyas by rolling your own here. For example, you're not escaping any invalid characters in your solution.

I would build your implementation on top of the existing [UriBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) class. By using it internally, I'm certain you'll save yourself many headaches down the road.

Comment: This is a good idea. Makes a lot of things easier. But I think it's still better then typing those strings by hand all the time. I rarely get them right at the first time.

Comment: Absolutely a worthwhile venture @t3chb0t!! I just wrote a similar little library for building SSRS report URLs about 2 weeks ago. The team loves it!

Comment: I'm afraid my excitement was premature ;-( I tried it out and checked the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/uribuilder.cs,634c7a8e7fe9ce50) for the `UriBuilder` and unfortunatelly it doesn't validate anything that would be useful in WPF context like the path needs to start with a slash or the % and ? need to be escaped. The uri it produces is not of much value for WPF resources either. I think I'll add regex here and there and it'll do.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone wanted to use the improved version here's the *final* one.

Credits go to [@denis](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/150729/59161).

```
abstract class PackUriBuilder
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<UriKind, Func<PackUriBuilder, Uri>> UriFactories = new Dictionary<UriKind, System.Func<PackUriBuilder, Uri>>
    {
        [UriKind.Absolute] = builder => new Uri(builder.AbsolutePath, UriKind.Absolute),
        [UriKind.Relative] = builder => new Uri(builder.RelativePath, UriKind.Relative),
    };

    private static readonly Dictionary<UriKind, Func<PackUriBuilder, string>> StringFactories = new Dictionary<UriKind, System.Func<PackUriBuilder, string>>
    {
        [UriKind.Absolute] = builder => builder.AbsolutePath,
        [UriKind.Relative] = builder => builder.RelativePath,
    };

    private UriKind _uriKind;

    protected PackUriBuilder(string path)
    {
        if (!path.StartsWith("/"))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(paramName: nameof(path), message: @"Path must start with ""/"".");
        }
        RelativePath = path;
        _uriKind = UriKind.Absolute;
    }

    public string Scheme => "pack";

    public string RelativePath { get; }

    public abstract string AbsolutePath { get; }

    public static implicit operator string (PackUriBuilder builder) => builder.ToString();

    public static implicit operator Uri(PackUriBuilder builder) => UriFactories[builder._uriKind](builder);

    public override string ToString() => StringFactories[_uriKind](this);   

    public Uri ToUri() => this;

    public PackUriBuilder Relative()
    {
        _uriKind = UriKind.Relative;
        return this;
    }

    public PackUriBuilder Absolute()
    {
        _uriKind = UriKind.Absolute;
        return this;
    }

    public static LocalAssemblyResourceFilePackUriBuilder LocalAssemblyResourceFile(string path)
    {
        return new LocalAssemblyResourceFilePackUriBuilder(path);
    }

    public static ReferencedAssemblyResourceFilePackUriBuilder ReferencedAssemblyResourceFile(string path, string assemblyShortName)
    {
        return new ReferencedAssemblyResourceFilePackUriBuilder(path, assemblyShortName);
    }

    public static ContentFilePackUriBuilder ContentFile(string path)
    {
        return new ContentFilePackUriBuilder(path);
    }

    public static SiteOfOriginPackUriBuilder SiteOfOrigin(string path)
    {
        return new SiteOfOriginPackUriBuilder(path);
    }
}
```

And the builders:

```
class LocalAssemblyResourceFilePackUriBuilder : PackUriBuilder
{
    public LocalAssemblyResourceFilePackUriBuilder(string path) : base(path) { }

    public override string AbsolutePath => $"{Scheme}://application:,,,{RelativePath}";
}

class ReferencedAssemblyResourceFilePackUriBuilder : PackUriBuilder
{
    private readonly string _assemblyShortName;
    private string _version;
    private string _publicKey;

    public ReferencedAssemblyResourceFilePackUriBuilder(string path, string assemblyShortName) : base(path)
    {
        _assemblyShortName = assemblyShortName;
    }

    private string VersionOrEmpty => string.IsNullOrEmpty(_version) ? string.Empty : $";{_version}";

    private string PublicKeyOrEmpty => string.IsNullOrEmpty(_publicKey) ? string.Empty : $";{_publicKey}";

    public ReferencedAssemblyResourceFilePackUriBuilder Version(string version)
    {
        _version = version;
        return this;
    }

    public ReferencedAssemblyResourceFilePackUriBuilder PublicKey(string publicKey)
    {
        _publicKey = publicKey;
        return this;
    }

    public override string AbsolutePath => $"{Scheme}://application:,,,/{_assemblyShortName}{VersionOrEmpty}{PublicKeyOrEmpty};component{RelativePath}";
}

class ContentFilePackUriBuilder : PackUriBuilder
{
    public ContentFilePackUriBuilder(string path) : base(path) { }

    public override string AbsolutePath => $"{Scheme}://application:,,,{RelativePath}";
}


class SiteOfOriginPackUriBuilder : PackUriBuilder
{
    public SiteOfOriginPackUriBuilder(string path) : base(path) { }

    public override string AbsolutePath => $"{Scheme}://siteoforigin:,,,{RelativePath}";
}
```

Comment: I really like the way you made `StringFactories` work, I forgot you can directly use the instance method, well done !

Comment: @denis yeah, the `switch` was ugly and if there was already one dictionary why not two ;-)

Comment: Can you link me to the documentation on the square brackets here [UriKind.Absolute] i don't know what they're purpose is in the code

Comment: @downrep_nation here you are [Pack URIs in WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069) sections "Absolute vs. Relative Pack URIs" & "Programming with Pack URIs"

Comment: @t3chb0t I think he meant this. `[UriKind.Absolute] = builder => new...`

Comment: Is letting `ToString()` throw an exception a normal thing? I'm not sure what the alternative is but something feels off about it to me

Comment: @downrep_nation see this [Dictionary Initializers](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2015/04/c-sharp-dictionary-initializers.aspx)

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 actually it isn't but I cannot see anything that could throw an exception on `ToString` here.

Comment: You're right, sorry. The original could on an invalid `UriKind`. Likewise this would to if you could somehow specify it manually, which you can't. Unless of course someone for some reason decided to make  another method or derived class that could set it to `RelativeOrAbsolute` without updating the dictionary

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 I think WPF does not use the third value (at least I didn't see it anywehre and the docs don't mention it) so it's rather unlikely someone will ever want to implement it. If you wanted to make something crash you can always access any field with reflection and change whatever you want to ;-) But I admit, the first version was just awaful with the exception but it was only there to satisfy the compiler that couldn't know that this case would _never_ be true.